# Sum and concat consecutive rows' values between 2 conditions and filter using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sum consecutive rows values between 2 conditions. Here is my data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no"],'B':["no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes"],'C': ["da","da","da","da","da","da","da","da","da","to","to","to","to","to","to"],'D': ['play','play','play','run','run','run','play','play','play','run','run','play','run','run','play'],'E':[2,5,1,4,6,13,7,8,3,9,1,4,3,5,7]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
```

In fact, when A="yes" and B="no", I would like to start adding rows values per D's values columns until A="no" and B="yes". This should be filtered by column C. Also, I would like to concatenate column A. I would like to get the following result:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","yes","yes"],'B':["no","no","no"],'C':["da","da","to"],'play':[8,18,4],'run':[4,0,8],'concatA':["yes/no/no/no","yes/no/no","yes/no/no"]},index=[0, 6,11])
```

Comment: Hard to understand. Let's break it down: what would you want to sum? which row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this `pandas` way (without loops) it might not be the cleanest code, that the world saw.

For clarity I broke it into smaller operations (it could be done with smaller number of operations):

```
df['state_change'] = (df['A'] == 'yes') & (df['B'] == 'no')
df['state_change_end'] = (df['A'] == 'no') & (df['B'] == 'yes')
df['group'] = df['state_change'].cumsum()
df['group_end'] = df['state_change_end'].cumsum()

#Filtering for summing
df['play'] = df['E'] * (df['D'] == 'play')
df['run'] = df['E'] * (df['D'] == 'run')

#Filtering out the rows, that shouldn't be summed
df_filtered = df[df['group']> df['group_end']].copy()
#Reseting index, to use it later
df_filtered['index'] = df_filtered.index

df_gb = df_filtered.groupby(df_filtered['group'])

df1 = df_gb.first()
df1['play'] = df_gb['play'].sum()
df1['run'] = df_gb['run'].sum()
df1['concatA'] = df_gb['A'].agg(lambda x : '/'.join(x))
df1.set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
df1[['A', 'B', 'C', 'play', 'run', 'concatA']]
```

Which produces required results:

```
    A   B   C   play    run concatA
0   yes no  da  8       4   yes/no/no/no
6   yes no  da  18      0   yes/no/no
11  yes no  to  4       8   yes/no/no
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. However, I found an issue by changing df.loc[[9,"B"]] by "no" and df.loc[[10,"A"]] by "yes". We should have the same result but it is not the case. Run column is summed and added to "da". But those sum belongs to "to" after index 9.

Comment: New dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no"],'B':["no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes"],'C': ["da","da","da","da","da","da","da","da","da","to","to","to","to","to","to"],'D': ['play','play','play','run','run','run','play','play','play','run','run','play','run','run','play'],'E':[2,5,1,4,6,13,7,8,3,9,1,4,3,5,7]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])`

Comment: Results: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes","yes","yes"],'B':["no","no","no"],'C':["da","da","to"],'play':[8,18,4],'run':[4,9,8],'concatA':["yes/no/no/no","yes/no/no","yes/no/no"]},index=[0, 6,11])` . I think we should do a group by column C. But I don't know how.